# Cannot access relation data of custom pivot model in self referencing many-to-many relationship

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I am building a system to describe a network. The network comprises a Nodes model which has a many-to-many relationship with itself...

```
class Node extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Node::class,
            'edges',
            'parent_id',
            'child_id'
        )
            ->withPivot(['id', 'parent_id', 'child_id', 'role_id'])
            ->as('edge');
    }
}
```

And I have a custom pivot table which represents edges...

```
class Edge extends Pivot
{

    protected $table = 'edges';

    public $incrementing = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'parent_id',
        'child_id',
        'role_id',
    ];

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
    }
}
```

The Edge model will need a lot of associated data, which cannot be stored on the edge itself, so I have the need to make relationships between the Edge and other tables For example the Role model, which is defined below...

```
class Role extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function edges()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Edge::class);
    }
}
```

I have created Resource classes for these models as follows..

```
class NetworkNodeResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'edge' => new EdgeResource($this->edge),
            'ownerNetwork' => $this->ownerNetwork
        ];
    }
}

class EdgeResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'role' => $this->role,
        ];
    }
}

class RoleResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'edges' => $this->edges
        ];
    }
}
```

The index method for the Edge and Role controllers are as follows...

```
public function index()
{
    $edges = Edge::with(['parent', 'child', 'role'])->get();
    return $edges;
}

public function index()
{
    $roles = Role::with(['edges'])->get();
    return $roles;
}
```

So, the Edges index shows all Edges, and the Roles connected to them. The Roles index shows all Roles and the Edges for each Role type. This is exactly what I want.

I order to explore and map the network I have built a recursive function below...

```
public function getOwnerNetwork(Node $node, $ownerNetwork = [])
{
    $ownerBranch = [];
    foreach ($node->children as $child) {
        if ($child->children->count() > 0) {
            $child->ownerNetwork = $this->getOwnerNetwork($child, $ownerNetwork);
        }
        $ownerBranch[] = new NetworkNodeResource($child);
    }
    return $ownerBranch;
}
```

The issue is that when I traverse the network using this function it results in the following returned data structure...

```
"data": {
    "id": 7,
    "edge": null,
    "ownerNetwork": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "edge": {
                "id": 4,
                "role": null,
            },
            "ownerNetwork": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "edge": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "role": null,
                    },
                    "ownerNetwork": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "edge": {
                                "id": 1,
                                "role": null,
                            },
                            "ownerNetwork": null
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "edge": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "role": null,
                    },
                    "ownerNetwork": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "edge": {
                "id": 5,
                "role": null,
            },
            "ownerNetwork": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Which clearly is not returning the relationship data I am expecting from the EdgeResource i.e. parent, child and role.

### EDIT

I have removed the proposed parent and child relations from the EdgeResource to make things simpler.

If I update the EdgeResource as below. I get the output I want, but I would like to understand why the relationship does not work and I am seemingly forced to do an explicit query to get the Role data. I suppose it results in the same SQL (more or less), but it makes me think I'm not understanding something.

```
class EdgeResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'role' => new RoleResource(Role::findOrFail($this->role_id)),
        ];
    }
}
```

```
"data": {
    "id": 7,
    "edge": null,
    "ownerNetwork": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "edge": {
                "id": 4,
                "role": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Director"
                },
            },
            "ownerNetwork": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "edge": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "role": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "Owner"
                        },
                    },
                    "ownerNetwork": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "edge": {
                                "id": 1,
                                "role": {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "name": "Owner"
                                },
                            },
                            "ownerNetwork": null
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "edge": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "role": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "Owner"
                        },
                    },
                    "ownerNetwork": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "edge": {
                "id": 5,
                "role": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Owner"
                },
            },
            "ownerNetwork": null
        }
    ]
}
```